# Using a function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a function in C that is crashing my code and I'm having a hard time figuring out what is going on. I have a function that looks like this:

```
#define cond int
void Enqueue(cond (*cond_func)());

cond read() {
return IsEmpty(some_global); // Returns a 1 or a 0 as an int
}

Enqueue(&read);
```

However, when running the above, it segfaults as soon as Enqueue is called. It doesn't even execute anything inside the function. I ran gdb and it just shows it dying as soon as Enqueue is called- no statements are processed within it. Any idea what is going on? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `#define cond int` <- what is this for? They invented `typedef` for a reason.

Comment: Naming your function `read` can lead to terrible problems. Better avoid it.

Comment: I was told that cond had to be a boolean, so I just made it an int.

Comment: [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) is the name of a very commonly used system call on POSIX systems.  Please don't use that name—at best it can lead to confusion; at worst tricky compiler and linker errors.

Comment: If it has to be a boolean, why not just `#include <stdbool.h>` and make it a `bool`? Once you've picked a new function name, `Enqueue(myfunc)` is better than `Enqueue(&myfunc)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more information about the code because according to my interpretation the code is working fine.I have tried this-

```
#define cond int
void Enqueue(cond (*cond_func)());
cond read() 
{
int some_global=1;
return IsEmpty(some_global); // Returns a 1 or a 0 as an int
}

int IsEmpty()
{
return 1;
}

void Enqueue(cond (*cond_func)())
{
printf("Perfect");
return 0;
}

int main()
{
Enqueue(&read);
return 0;
}
```

And it is working fine.

Comment: `main()` and `IsEmpty()` should have a return type, it's not the 1970s anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define cond int
```

was meant to be:

```
typedef int cond;
```

Although defining an alias for your function pointer might be much more reasonable here, for example:

```
typedef int (*FncPtr)(void);

int read() {
    printf("reading...");
}

void foo(FncPtr f) {
    (*f)();
}

int main() {
    foo(read);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef bool cond;

void Enqueue(cond (*cond_func)(void)) {
    printf("In Enqueue()...\n");
    cond status = cond_func();
    printf("In Enqueue, 'status' is %s\n", status ? "true" : "false");
}

bool IsEmpty(const int n) {
    return true;
}

cond my_cond_func(void) {
    printf("In my_cond_func()...\n");
    return IsEmpty(1);
}

int main(void) {
    Enqueue(my_cond_func);
    return 0;
}
```

Your problem is likely coming from somewhere else, such as your definition of `Enqueue()` which you don't provide, or the fact your function is called `read()` and is conflicting with the more common function of that name.

Comment: Read was shortened for something else for brevity. I totally agree with that.